# tokenize function that doesn't split up string properly

Tags: haskell

I'm working on some code for an assignment that should tokenize a String. It takes in 3 strings as arguments, and returns a list of strings. The arguments are the string that should be tokenized, a string, `s`, of characters that should stand as a single string in the list if it occurs in `s`, and a string of characters that should be removed from `s`.

Some examples that we should get:

> `tokenize "ab cd -ef" "" " "` should give: `["ab","cd","-ef"]`

and

> `tokenize "ab cd -ef" "-" " "` should give: `["ab","cd","-","ef"]`

I've looked online and in books for help, and my code gives correct output for some of the examples, but not all. I'm still learning Haskell, so I don't understand all of the help other has gotten online(and I don't want to copy&paste)

Here is my code so far:

```
tokenize :: String -> [Char] -> [Char] -> [String]
tokenize [] imp rem = []
tokenize (x:xs) imp rem = if null imp && null rem then [(x:xs)]
                            else if null imp && rem == " " then ord (x:xs)
                            else if finnes rem x then tokenize xs imp rem
                            else if finnes imp x then [x]:(tokenize xs imp rem)
                            else [x] : (tokenize xs imp rem)

ord :: String -> [String]
ord [] = []
ord s = takeWhile (/= ' ') s : (ord (fjernOrd s ' '))

fjernOrd :: String -> Char -> String
fjernOrd [] c = []
fjernOrd xs c = if (head xs) /= c then fjernOrd (tail xs) c else tail xs

--wrote my own version of elem to check if a character exists in a string
finnes :: String -> Char -> Bool
finnes "" c = False
finnes (s:xs) c | s == c = True
                | otherwise = finnes xs c
```

All the other functions run as they should when I try them, so the problem is in the tokenize-function.

It works when I put `" "` for `rem`, and `""` for `imp`, but not when i put characters in `imp`(f.ex. "-")

For example when I write `tokenize "ab cd -ef"`, I get `["ab","cd","-ef"]`, which is correct, but when I type `tokenize "ab cd -ef" "-" " "`, I should get
`["ab","cd","-","ef"]`, but instead I get `["a","b","c","d","-","e","f"]`

Comment: hm... not sure I follow what your code is trying to do... but I would approach this with the idea of making exactly one pass through the input string; i.e. looking at the first character in the string, do the right thing depending on whether it's in the whitelist or blacklist, and call `tokenize` with the rest of the input string. Something like: `tokenize (x:xs) whitelist blacklist = res ++ tokenize xs whitelist blacklist`

Comment: so what should return `tokenize "ab cd e-f" "-" " "`? I guess `["ab","cd","e", "-", "f"]`.  And for `tokenize "ab cd -ef" "-" "f"`?. Up to your description, `f` should be remove, so the output should be `["ab","cd",  "-", "e"]`. Am I wrong?

Comment: **N.B.**   As per [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=no&tl=en&text=ord%0Afjern%20ord%0Afinnes), in Norwegian, *"ord"* = "word", *"fjern ord"* = "remove words", *"finnes"* = "exists".

Answer (score 0):

So this is a rather verbose implementation of what I think you want... which is not so clear to me. The idea is: *For each token apply a function which converts them into a list of string. Then concat all results into one*. From this definition is more less clear that you need something like below:

```
import Data.List
tokenize s imp del = concatMap g $ words s
                     ^^^^^^^^  ^   ^^^^^^^  
                     |         |   |- This the list of token
                     |         |- This is a function that apply the logic to each token. We'll think about this later
                     |- This will apply g to each token a concat the results
```

`concatMap` and `words` are given by `Data.List` module. We need to think only about `g`. Now for each token you need an accumulator which behaves as follow:

*for each char in the token: if the char is in `del`, just ignore it and continue. if the char is in `imp`, build a string, accumulate it and continue. Otherwise join the char with the last accumulate value* **if such a value is not in** `imp`.

Due to the fact that you need to check twice if a character is in `imp` or not, It makes sense to keep track of such check in your accumulator. Therefore the type of it should be `([String], Bool)`. The `[String]` will be holding your strings, whereas the `Bool` is a flag saying *"Hey!, The last value you append to the list is an important one"*. having said all of this, the implementation quite follows it word by word

```
import Data.List

type DelString = [Char]
type ImpString = [Char]

tokenize :: String -> ImpString -> DelString -> [String]
tokenize s imp del = concatMap (fst . foldr (g imp del) ([], False) ) $ words s
                                ^^^   ^^^^^ 
--                              |     |- Remeber this foldr is apply to each token
--                              |- The final result is a Tuple. Take the first element

g :: ImpString -> DelString -> Char -> ([String], Bool) -> ([String], Bool)
g imp del c acc@(l, b)
  | c `elem` del = acc                   -- If c in del, just continue without touching the acc
  | c `elem` imp = ([c] : l, True)       -- If c is important, append it as a String and set the flag to True
  | otherwise    = case acc of
      ([]  ,     _)  -> ([c] : l, False) -- Probably you can get rid of this... but just in case (no pun intended)
      (_   ,  True)  -> ([c] : l, False) -- The case of previous value being important
      (s:ss, False) -> ((c:s):ss, False) -- The regular case



> tokenize "ab cd -ef" "" ""
["ab","cd","-ef"]
> tokenize "ab cd -ef" "-" ""
["ab","cd","-","ef"]
> tokenize "ab cd -ef" "-" "c"
["ab","d","-","ef"]
> tokenize "ab c#d -e*f" "-*#" "c"
["ab","#","d","-","e","*","f"]
```